# GPUimageVideoCamera for android

Tags: android, compression, gpuimage

I am using GPUImage library to compress a video in my iOs app (GPUimageVideoCamera)
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/

I have worked with it on iOS and it is very fast

I want to do the same in my android app, but it seems that GPUImageMovie class doesn't exist in android library:
https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/tree/master/library/src/jp/co/cyberagent/android/gpuimage

It seems that android library only work on images (no video).

Anyone know if this library can do the job? If not, did someone developed GPUImage all library? If not, what is the best library i can use that can do the job as fast as GPUImage library do.

That's what GPUimageVideoCamera do in iOs (Filtering live video):

To filter live video from an iOS device's camera, you can use code like the following:

```
GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

GPUImageFilter *customFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] initWithFragmentShaderFromFile:@"CustomShader"];
GPUImageView *filteredVideoView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, viewWidth, viewHeight)];

  // Add the view somewhere so it's visible

    [videoCamera addTarget:customFilter];
    [customFilter addTarget:filteredVideoView];

[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

This sets up a video source coming from the iOS device's back-facing camera, using a preset that tries to capture at 640x480. This video is captured with the interface being in portrait mode, where the landscape-left-mounted camera needs to have its video frames rotated before display. A custom filter, using code from the file CustomShader.fsh, is then set as the target for the video frames from the camera. These filtered video frames are finally displayed onscreen with the help of a UIView subclass that can present the filtered OpenGL ES texture that results from this pipeline.

The fill mode of the GPUImageView can be altered by setting its fillMode property, so that if the aspect ratio of the source video is different from that of the view, the video will either be stretched, centered with black bars, or zoomed to fill.

For blending filters and others that take in more than one image, you can create multiple outputs and add a single filter as a target for both of these outputs. The order with which the outputs are added as targets will affect the order in which the input images are blended or otherwise processed.

Also, if you wish to enable microphone audio capture for recording to a movie, you'll need to set the audioEncodingTarget of the camera to be your movie writer, like for the following:

```
videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
```

Is there a library that can do the same in android?

Comment: Did you figure out any solution to this problem. I used GPUImage for android by cyberagent. It works fine. Now i want my app to recored a video and apply filters on that video just like instagram. GPUimage does not help on that until i do every frame individually which is very time consuming and memory leak prone . Any tips how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Any luck with this issue???

Comment: @aNoviceGuy did you found any solution for this?